# Terraform output configuration

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a Terraform problem. I want to display output like availability zone. I have 2 EC2 instances, and a datasource to fetch details like availability zone for one of the instances through filter parameter, and forward the result to an output, but I am getting an error.

---

Main.tf

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2-1"{
  ami="ami-0a54aef4ef3b5f881"
  instance_type="t2.micro"
  tags={
    Name="Instance-1"
  }
  depends_on=[aws_instance.ec2-2]
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2-2"{
  ami="ami-026dea5602e368e96"
  instance_type="t2.micro"
  tags={
    Name="Instance-2"
  }
}

data "aws_instance" "instancesearch"{
  filter {
    name="tag:Name"
    values=["Instance-2"]
  }
}

output "instanceid"{
  value = data.aws_instance.instancesearch.availability_zone
}
```

---

```
terraform plan result:


Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...

The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be

persisted to local or remote state storage.


data.aws_instance.instancesearch: Refreshing state...


Error: Your query returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again.


  on main.tf line 19, in data "aws_instance" "instancesearch":

  19: data "aws_instance" "instancesearch"{
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use a separate data source to get the availability zone. You can get it as an attribute on the resource itself. Try this:

```
output "availability_zone" {
  value = aws_instance.ec2-2.availability_zone
}
```